# Using html data to create a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery.

I want to create several divs that will work as buttons and each one will open a certain object.

In order to create a single function I was thinking of doing this:

**In hmtl:**

```
<div class="btn example" data-open=".example">
Example
</div>
```

**In js:**

```
var $target;
var needed = 1;

$('.btn').click(function() {
    $target = $($(this).data("open"));
    openFunction(needed);
});
```

The openFunction is defined before and will handle the needed animations for the object, it will select the $target for it.

It is not working (clearly), how should I do it?

Thanks

Edit: I want the $target to be $('.[the data in the clicked div]')

**$target = $($(this).data("open")) doesn't make it $target = $('.example')**

Edit2: The openFunction:

```
function openFunction(x){
    if (x > 0) {
        $target.animate({
        right: -menuSpace
        }, {duration: animationTime});
    }
}
```

With the vars menuSpace and animationTime defined. The function works fine if I define $target manually to one div.

Comment: Post the `openFunction` function!

Comment: I don't understand, with your example code, `$target` is just going to be itself (the clicked div)...

Comment: I want the $target to be $('.[the data in the clicked div]')

Comment: Is `$target` defined in the same scope as `openFunction`?

Comment: Your code seems to work.  Note you need to `position:absolute` `example` class: http://jsfiddle.net/4hh482rr/1/

Comment: But unfortunately it doesn't.
$target = $($(this).data("open"))
doesn't make it $target = $('.example')

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you passing 'needed' to the function and then check for the global 'needed' while receiving it as 'x' and not doing anything with x at all? I think you want to do `penFunction(target, needed)`, no.. ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, I've corrected it. I'm pasting a simpler version of the function so it's easy to fix the problem.

Comment: Why don't; you try passing the defined $target from your click to your openFunction? In your click just define `var object = $($(this).data("open"));` and then run `openFunction(needed, object)`and instead of using a global `$target`, used the passed object to animate... You are using globals where you a better of without them.

Comment: The problem is I do need it to become a global because the script needs to know what object was moved before (like a menu being slide open) to move it again later (closing said menu).

I have dozens of hidden menus that will slide open depending on what is clicked.

I want to store what is open for when I call the closeFunction and I want to avoid needing to define a script for every button (using a single one that calls the openFunction and uses data on the button to define the global var).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure where it is going wrong in your script, but the following works:

```
var $target;    
$('.btn').click(function() {
    // we know the following works
    var object = $($(this).data("open"));
    openFunction(1, object);
});
function openFunction(x, object){
    if (x > 0) {
        // lets assign globally that which are opening here
        $target = object;
        object.animate({
            "margin-left" : 200 + "px"
        }, 2000, function(){
            // lets prove the target contains the actual object
            alert($target.html().trim());
        });
    }
}
```

Yes, I changed some values (like 'right' is now 'margin-left') because I'm not using your CSS, but it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn example" data-open=".example">
    Example
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $target;
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        var object = $($(this).data("open"));
        openFunction(1, object);
    });
    function openFunction(x, object){
        if (x > 0) {
            $target = object;
            object.animate({
             "margin-left" : 200 + "px"
            }, 2000, function(){
                alert($target.html().trim());
            });
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Update

I added the 'globalisation' of the variable, and proved the globalisation by seeing what the contents are of the element. I also think setting it in your 'openFunction' is safer, as it is the place where you actually decide to open something or not. Although I think you;de be better of doing all this with a class (add a class to open called, say, '.open' and then you can find all the open ones by doing `$(".open")`and you could put your animation in the CSS3 transitions, which would speed up your site...)

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I didn't change the global part (the function will open sub menus also in the future so I'll need to have several global vars with which sub menus to open, and the needed var (x) will be the number of menus to open) but I've written the code again and it worked. I probably missed some dot or some quote (I really hate when I do this and lose hours trying to figure something doesn't work). Thanks again!

Comment: No prob, it usually is just missing a letter or something and it does become frustrating. Good luck with the rest of it :)